# Chrome webRequest event not firing on Chrome start

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a Chrome extension to workaround Steam's annoying URL warning page. See this for example: https://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/?url=http://67.69.104.76:84/marville/photos/planes/comet-162a.jpg

What I have so far works except when clicking a link would launch Chrome, in which case the Steam notice page is displayed.
Here is the page on webrequest: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

Any idea how I might get this to work at launch too?

**background.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(

    function (details) {
        var url = details.url;
        var host = url.substring(43);

        return { redirectUrl: host };
    },

    {
        urls: ["*://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/*"],
        types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
    },

    ["blocking"]

);
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Steam Link Filter Redirect",
    "description": "Bypasses Steam link filtering.",
    "version": "1.1",
    "background": {"scripts":["background.js"]},
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "*://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/*",
        "webRequestBlocking"
     ],

    "icons": { 
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "19": "icon19.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png" 
    }
}
```

Comment: The `webRequest` API is only available after the extension is initialized. Try the [`chrome.declarativeWebRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest) API instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, of course, that your code executes too late, after `onBeforeRequest` stage is done for the opening page. I don't think you can work around that.

You probably need to add a fallback mechanism. I suggest adding a content script that is injected in the linkfilter page and changes the page URL to the required one, for example:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
  "matches": ["*://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/*"],
  "js": ["redirect.js"]
} ],
```

redirect.js:

```
location.replace(
  decodeURIComponent( location.href.replace(/^.*?\?url=/, "") )
);
```

(I've made it more robust than `.substring(43)`)